# Hash keys behavior

Tags: perl, autovivification

```
perl -Mstrict -wlE 'my %h; say grep 0, $h{poluted}; say keys %h'
```

output

```
poluted
```

and

```
perl -Mstrict -wlE 'my %h; say grep 0, my @r= $h{poluted}; say keys %h'
```

gives no output.

I would like to know why outputs are different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Aliasing

In Perl's looping constructs `map`, `grep` and `for`, the `$_` variable is *aliased* to each current item. While the `$_` may be read-only, it always represents a valid scalar value.

For example, the following code dies:

```
$_ = 1 for 1, 2, 3;  # constants are read-only
```

but this works:

```
my @nums = (1, 2, 3);
$_ = 1 for @nums;  # @nums isn't read-only
```

Notice that assignments perform a copy, but an alias associates a name with an existing scalar.

#### The two `undef` values

Perl has two kinds of `undef`:

- A scalar may be set to represent `undef`. For example:

  ```
  my $foo;  # is this kind of undef
  $foo = 1; # isn't undef any more
  ```
- A special globally unique scalar that represents an readonly `undef` value, e.g. returned when you access an uninitialized array index in an rvalue context. In the Perl API, this is `&PL_sv_undef`. You can obtain a reference to this value, e.g. `\undef`, and can *alias* a variable to it.

#### The two ways of accessing a hash value

Internally, hash entries are fetched with `hv_fetch` or `hv_fetch_ent`. As arguments, both take a hash, a key, and a flag telling them whether the access is read-only.

If this is a read-only access and the element doesn't exist, a null pointer will be returned, which manifests itself as the `undef` value in Perl space. This `undef` value is not connected to the hash. Ergo, `not exists $hash{foo}` implies `not defined $hash{foo}`.

But if it isn't read-only and the element doesn't exist, a new entry is created, which is then returned. However, this entry is initially `undef`, until it is set to another value via an assignment.

#### So why doesn't the code in the question work as expected?

```
grep 0, $h{polluted}
```

Argument lists for looping constructs are aliased to `$_`. If the expressions in the list are constants or subroutines, then nothing spectacular happens. But when they are variable accesses, then this implies a read-write access.

So, to obtain the value of `$h{polluted}`, Perl apparently does an access in read-write mode. If we look at the opcodes for this expression, we do in fact see:

```
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*h] s
5  <1> rv2hv sKR/1
6  <$> const[PV "polluted"] s/BARE
7  <2> helem sKM/2                # <-- hash element access, "M" flag is set!
8  <@> grepstart K
9  <|> grepwhile(other->a)[t2] vK
a      <$> const[IV 0] s
           goto 9
```

The `M` stands for `MOD`, which means an lvalue/read-write access.

#### Why does this behavior make “sense”

In `for`-loops, having `$_` be an alias to the current element can be genuinly useful. In `map` and `grep`, this is a performance hack to avoid the copy of a whole scalar. Aliasing is much cheaper, as this only implies the copy of a single pointer.

Comment: For inquisitive folks, it might be worth mentioning that the opcodes can be obtained through running something like `$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -E ...`. Syntax documentation found in the [`B::Concise`](https://metacpan.org/module/B::Concise) pod pages

Comment: It is still unclear to me as to why `grep` always seem to access its arguments r/w. This is not the case with user-defined subroutines, see: `perl -le 'sub mod { $_[0] = "modified" } sub nomod { $_[0] } sub refd : lvalue  { $_[0] }  mod($h{created}); nomod($h{discarded}); $v=refd($h{roref}); refd($h{rwref})=1; print for keys(%h)'` which prints: `created\nrwref`.

Comment: @user2719058 In all those cases, the hash is accessed as `<2> helem sKM/LVDEFER,2`. I have no idea what *that* means, but it seems to be Yet Another Performance Hack.

Comment: tnx, so `grep 0, @{[ $h{poluted} ]}` should be used to prevent hash pollution.

Comment: @amon Well, I guess it enables Perl to detect if the argument alias is modified by the subroutine, and infer if the subroutine provides an lvalue context. I am still wondering why that does not apply to `grep`.